# How to add vendor resources to application.css and reference it in web page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm using rails 4, and using bower install resource in `vendor/assets/bower_components` directory, for example, bootstrap is in `/vendor/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`.

I add `require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`, but when i view a page, it shows `couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
  (in /home/vagrant/Share/webapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:15)`

And I wonder how to reference those resource in rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')` to `config/application.rb` and retry.

Comment: I googled after ask this question, and find the solution is helpful, So I post it.

Comment: I'm afraid my English is poor, is it that I should post the solution in question comment instead of post in answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in your application.css file. Hope it helps.

```
 *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/bower_components/.
```

Comment: Is it giving same error message? Try  writing it below the line  *= require_tree and check the spaces .

Comment: Yes, the error is the same, I google it, and find add `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')` to `config/application`, then  `require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap`, it will work.

Comment: The problem with the Rails.root.join method, is you then loose control over the order which the files are loaded.  I wanted to load the vendor/... files at a particular order relative to tree and self.  Short of a complete reworking of the assets system in this app, this was the best solution.